# Custom SVG Map with markers

Tags: highcharts, maps

I'm trying to plot map markers on a custom svg map that I generated with the online tool provided (https://highcharts.github.io/map-from-svg/). I'm trying to plot markers on a building interior by lat/long coordinate. Ultimately I want to create something like the marker cluster demo (https://www.highcharts.com/demo/maps/marker-clusters) with my custom SVG map.

My questions are:

1. Is it possible to plot markers on a custom SVG map by lat/long?
2. If so, how do I go about doing this? Do I geolocate the corners of the map to plot the markers by lat/long, or do I convert the marker locations to x/y on the map?
3. If I geolocate the custom SVG map, where do I add this data in the object?
4. If I convert the lat/long to x/y on the map, how do I go about this?

I have managed to convert my SVG into map Data using the online tool. I've searched through the docs, but I'm not putting the pieces together on how to do this.

Edit: I should mention that I'm using highcharts-angular (https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-angular)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use [cluster](https://api.highcharts.com/highmaps/plotOptions.mappoint.cluster) map should be prepare map to have a reference to the coordinate system, the generated SVG map is drawn without this.

This article describes how to create your own map with a datum, you need to generate the map as GeoJSON/TopoJSON and then you can reference lat/lon.

https://www.highcharts.com/docs/maps/custom-geojson-maps

In this [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/highcharts-angular-map-sajsa1?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) you can see how to load SVG map with Highmaps in Angular.

Comment: Thanks Sabastian for your response. So to be clear I need to import my SVG into an app like QGIS, then go through the process of georeferencing along these lines https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HC21k7mL_-w Is that correct?

Comment: You can convert your map for use with Highcharts Maps.